# how to give attr_accessor to all the instance variables in class ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class A
   attr_reader :foo, :bar
   def initialize
      @foo = "foo"
      @bar = 2
      .....
      .....
      # many variables like this
   end
end
```

In this class has 2 variables. I want to give attr_accessor to all the instance variables like "attr_accessor *". is this possible?

Comment: If you want less typing for things like this, there are also libraries like (my) [attr_extras](https://github.com/barsoom/attr_extras) that get rid of some boilerplate.

Comment: When you give an example please include complete code. The lines `...` are not needed, but requires anyone who wants to cut and paste your code to strip them out. They should be removed. Same for data given in examples (not relevant here).  `[1,5,2...]`, for example, should be written,  `arr = [1,5,2]`, with the array just large enough to make the point of the question. By including the variable `arr`, readers can refer to it in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hackish and limited to your specific example, but just answering the question (in its second incarnation):

```
class A
  def initialize
    @foo = 1
    @bar = 2
    #add as many instance variables you need
  end
  attr_accessor *A.new.instance_variables.map { |s| s[1..-1] }
end

obj = A.new
obj.foo     #=> 1
obj.bar     #=> 2
obj.bar = 3 #=> 3
obj.bar     #=> 3
```

See [`Object#instance_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is implemented already and it's called `OpenStruct`.

```
require 'ostruct'
a = OpenStruct.new(foo: 1, bar: 2)
a.foo # => 1
a.bar # => 2
```

(*at least, I'm guessing this is what you want*)

Comment: sorry I updated the question. Please suggest me for this

Answer (score 2):

Your class doesn't know about variables that are assigned in #initialize. It's rather uncommon to do what you're asking for, so I'll answer this with a "no". Technically it's possible somehow, but I wouldn't follow that path.

Comment: If you want to know how it might be done, I'd do it with `method_missing` and `define_method`.

Comment: But yes, totally not recommended

Comment: sorry I updated the question. Please suggest me for this

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use a hash as attribute. Since you only access the hash, without needing to replace it, `attr_reader` is enough. For the initialization, you can use `**kwargs`:

```
class A
   attr_reader :attributes
   def initialize(**kwargs)
     @attributes = kwargs
   end
end

a = A.new(foo: 1, bar: 2)
puts a.attributes[:foo]
#=> 1
puts a.attributes[:bar]
#=> 2

a.attributes[:baz] = 3
puts a.attributes[:baz]
# => 3

puts a.attributes[:bak].inspect
# => nil
```

Comment: sorry I updated the question. Please suggest me for this

Answer (score 1):

A Struct defines a class with an initialize method and all accessors in one go:

```
A = Struct.new(:foo, :bar)

an_a = A.new("foo", 1)
p an_a.methods # => [:foo, :bar, :foo=, :bar=, ...]
```

Comment: sorry I updated the question. Please suggest me for this